# JSONDecoder fails to parse a list of maps

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I have prepared [a simple test Playground at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJson1.playground) to demo my problem:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

My Swift code:

```
struct TopResponse: Codable {
    let results: [Top]
}
struct Top: Codable {
    let uid: Int
    let elo: Int
    let given: String
    let photo: String?
    let motto: String?
    let avg_score: String?
    let avg_time: String?
}

let url = URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
    data, response, error in
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    guard let data2 = data,
          let tops = try? decoder.decode(TopResponse.self, from:
                                            data2) else { return }
    print(tops.results[4].given)
}
task.resume()
```

fails to parse the fetched JSON string and does not print anything.

What could be the problem here please?

Comment: `try?`? That means: If there is a thrown error, I don't want to catch it, I just want to ignore it even if it could give me an explanation on why it failed with precise error or even just an hint. Start by doing a proper `do`/`try`/`catch`, and you should see why...

Comment: You'll see two errors then: `results`, there is no key `"results"` in your JSON, but `data`. And `avg_score` is a `Double`, not a `String`. How did I know that? Just by reading the errors thrown first, and then checking why I got them with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What's wrong with your code?

```
try?
```

That's the main culprit.
Why? You are ignoring the error thrown by the `decode(_:from:)`. **You are ignoring the error** that could give you the exact reason or at least a hint on why it failed. Instead, write a proper `do { try ... } catch { ... }`.

So:

```
guard let data2 = data,
      let tops = try? decoder.decode(TopResponse.self, from:
                                        data2) else { return }
print(tops.results[4].given)
```

=>

```
guard let data2 = data else { return }
do {
let tops = try decoder.decode(TopResponse.self, from: data2)
print(tops.results[4].given)
} catch {
    print("Got error while parsing: \(error)")
    print("With response: \(String(data: data2, encoding: .utf8))") //Just in case because I've seen plenty of code where expected JSON wasn't the one received: it was an error, doc changed, etc...
}
```

Output for the first print:

```
$>Got error while parsing: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"results\", intValue: nil) (\"results\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Fix:

```
struct TopResponse: Codable {
    let results: [Top]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case results = "data"
    }
}
```

Or rename `results` with `data`.

Then, next error:

```
$>Got error while parsing: typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "avg_score", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Extract from JSON:

```
    "avg_score": 20.4
```

It's not a `String` (the value it's not between double quotes), that's a `Double`.

Fix:

```
let avg_score: String?
```

=>

```
let avg_score: Double?
```